# Acelerar aplicación Android que rastrea imágen pixel a pixel

Tags: android, imagen

Estoy programando una aplicación en *Android Studio* que saca una **foto** con la **cámara** y la rastrea **pixel a pixel** en **busca de colores**.

Básicamente, lo que hace es recorrer todas las filas con un bucle `for` y con otro `for` dentro del primero recorre todos los píxeles de cada fila.
En cada píxel uso `Bitmap.getPixel()` y después `Color.red(pixel)`, `Color.green(pixel)` y `Color.blue(pixel)` para hacer los cálculos.

El problema viene en las imágenes con resolución alta, que se eterniza recorriendo todo el ancho y alto.

Mientras lo depuro (directamente en terminal físico), me fijo en la pestaña *Android Monitor* de *Android Studio* y veo que el procesador está con un uso muy bajo y la memoria marca unos *3MB libres de 40MB*.

¿Tengo el problema en los *40MB* de memoria que utiliza la aplicación en el teléfono?
¿Se puede incrementar la cantidad de memoria que utilizará la aplicación cuando corra en el terminal?

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer este proceso más rápido?

Comment: Prueba con activar el HardwareAcceleration https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Los resultados eran similares con «hardware aceleration» tanto activado, como desactivado.

Answer (score 1):

utiliza hilos, o tbien puedes usar el nuevo fork join de java, yo utilizaria hilos, creando un hilo por cada columna de la imagen, claro todo estp se vera limitado por las capacidades del telefono, pero yo procesaria tal vez unos 10 hilos a la vez y veria el performance con las herramientas de visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Tras implementar una solución multihilo sin mejoras, me decidí por usar NDK. 
Existe una librería escrita en C++ para rotar, escalar imágenes, etc...

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

La utilicé como base, generando mis propios métodos para conseguir exactamente lo que yo quería y mi aplicación es 10 veces más rápida ahora.